# A POST request on a page with HTTPS is done automatically in HTTPS?

Tags: javascript, https, ajax

If I make a request to `page.php` (AJAX) with JavaScript from a HTTPS page, the request is automatically made ​​`page.php` directly with HTTPS or HTTP? If HTTP, how to send a request (to the same domain) with HTTPS with pure JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

More information is needed to be 100% sure (code sample, framework, ...), but the likely answer is **yes**.

If you POST with a **relative URL**, then the same host/port as the current page will be used.

You can open Chrome/Firefox's inspector to see how the browser actually made the request.

If you give the browser an absolute URL, then you can specify the http/https in the URL.

Comment: Someone edited my answer, but the comma they removed was not an optional comma in English. Please don't edit my answers to use improper grammar.